# How can I update only cells in RxDataSources that are changed and not all of them?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Im using `RxSwift` and `RxDataSources` to create table view.

But I do not want to reload all cells when only one cell is changed.

How can I achieve this with `RxSwift`?

Current solution.

```
private let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<VehicleCheckDeteilsSectionModel>()
```

Cell configuration.

```
dataSource.configureCell = {[weak self] (_, tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath, item: VehicleCheckDeteilsCellModel) in
    return self?.deteilsCellFactory(in: tableView, for: indexPath, with: item) ?? UITableViewCell()
}
```

Bund of the data.

```
let sectionModelObserver = viewModel?.tableSectionModel.asObservable().observeOn(MainScheduler.instance).share()
sectionModelObserver?.bind(to: self.deteilsTableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource)).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement `AnimatableSectionModelType` on `VehicleCheckDeteilsSectionModel` and make your dataSource `RxTableViewSectionedAnimatedDataSource`.